# gather multiple columns with nested, repeated measures

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset of people (`pid`) of different types (`type2=c("dad", "mom", "kid"`; and for ease, `type=c("a", "b", "c")`) nested in households (`hid`) with repeated measurements (`time`).

- Some variables like `v1_` are asked to everyone, but the values are spread across three columns. For instance, `v1_a` contains the values for all of the dads (`type==a`).
- Variables like `v2_` are only asked of dads and moms (a's and b's), and the values are spread across two columns.
- Variables like `v3` are also only asked to dads and moms, but the values are contained in one column.
- Variables like `v4` are asked to everyone, and the values are contained in one column.

Have:

```
   hid pid type type2 time v1_a v1_b v1_c v2_a v2_b v3 v4
1    1   1    a   dad    1    6   NA   NA    2   NA  4  3
2    1   2    b   mom    1   NA    2   NA   NA    5  6  6
3    1   3    c   kid    1   NA   NA    1   NA   NA NA  5
4    2   4    a   dad    1    3   NA   NA    6   NA  2  6
5    2   5    b   mom    1   NA    5   NA   NA    2  4  3
6    2   6    c   kid    1   NA   NA    3   NA   NA NA  5
7    1   1    a   dad    2    3   NA   NA    2   NA  4  3
8    1   2    b   mom    2   NA    3   NA   NA    5  6  6
9    1   3    c   kid    2   NA   NA    2   NA   NA NA  5
10   2   4    a   dad    2    2   NA   NA    6   NA  2  6
11   2   5    b   mom    2   NA    3   NA   NA    2  4  3
12   2   6    c   kid    2   NA   NA    2   NA   NA NA  5
```

Here is the end result I want:

```
   hid pid type type2 time v1 v2 v3 v4
1    1   1    a   dad    1  6  2  4  3
2    1   2    b   mom    1  2  5  6  6
3    1   3    c   kid    1  1 NA NA  5
4    2   4    a   dad    1  3  6  2  6
5    2   5    b   mom    1  5  2  4  3
6    2   6    c   kid    1  3 NA NA  5
7    1   1    a   dad    2  3  2  4  3
8    1   2    b   mom    2  3  5  6  6
9    1   3    c   kid    2  2 NA NA  5
10   2   4    a   dad    2  2  6  2  6
11   2   5    b   mom    2  3  2  4  3
12   2   6    c   kid    2  2 NA NA  5
```

I'm looking for a `tidyverse` approach that will handle a larger actual use case of mixed variables as shown here. The variable naming is consistent. Where do I go after `gather()`?

```
library(tidyverse)
df_have <- data.frame(hid=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
                            1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                      pid=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
                            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                      type=c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c",
                             "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
                      type2=c("dad", "mom", "kid", "dad", "mom", "kid",
                              "dad", "mom", "kid", "dad", "mom", "kid"),
                      time=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                             2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                      v1_a=c(6, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA,
                             3, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA),
                      v1_b=c(NA, 2, NA, NA, 5, NA,
                             NA, 3, NA, NA, 3, NA),
                      v1_c=c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 3,
                             NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2),
                      v2_a=c(2, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA,
                             2, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA),
                      v2_b=c(NA, 5, NA, NA, 2, NA,
                             NA, 5, NA, NA, 2, NA),
                      v3=c(4, 6, NA, 2, 4, NA,
                           4, 6, NA, 2, 4, NA),
                      v4=c(3, 6, 5, 6, 3, 5,
                           3, 6, 5, 6, 3, 5)
                      )
df_want <- data.frame(hid=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
                            1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                      pid=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
                            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                      type=c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c",
                             "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
                      type2=c("dad", "mom", "kid", "dad", "mom", "kid",
                              "dad", "mom", "kid", "dad", "mom", "kid"),
                      time=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                             2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                      v1=c(6, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3,
                           3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2),
                      v2=c(2, 5, NA, 6, 2, NA,
                           2, 5, NA, 6, 2, NA),
                      v3=c(4, 6, NA, 2, 4, NA,
                           4, 6, NA, 2, 4, NA),
                      v4=c(3, 6, 5, 6, 3, 5,
                           3, 6, 5, 6, 3, 5)
                      )

df_have %>%
  gather(key, value, -hid, -pid, -type, -type2, -time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets me there, but the `filter(!is.na(value))` step seems like a hack. Better ideas?

```
df_test <- 
df_have %>%
  gather(key, value, -hid, -pid, -type, -time, -type2) %>%
  mutate(key = str_replace(key, "_.*", "")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  arrange(time, hid, type, pid)
```

Update from @www:

```
df_test <- 
df_have %>%
  gather(key, value, -hid, -pid, -type, -time, -type2, na.rm=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(key = str_replace(key, "_.*", "")) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  arrange(time, hid, type, pid)
```

Comment: You can set `na.rm = TRUE` in the `gather`: `gather(key, value, -hid, -pid, -type, -time, -type2, na.rm = TRUE)`. By doing this, no need to use `filter(!is.na(value))`.

Comment: Great suggestion. I did not consider that `gather()` had na handling.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea using `coalesce` from `dplyr` and `map` from `purrr`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Set target column names
cols <- paste0("v", 1:4)

# Coalesce the numbers based on column names
nums <- map(cols, ~coalesce(!!!as.list(df_have %>% select(starts_with(.x)))))

# Create a data frame
nums_df <- nums %>%
  setNames(cols) %>%
  as_data_frame()

# Create the final output by bind_cols
df_test <- df_have %>%
  select(-starts_with("v")) %>%
  bind_cols(nums_df)

df_test
#    hid pid type type2 time v1 v2 v3 v4
# 1    1   1    a   dad    1  6  2  4  3
# 2    1   2    b   mom    1  2  5  6  6
# 3    1   3    c   kid    1  1 NA NA  5
# 4    2   4    a   dad    1  3  6  2  6
# 5    2   5    b   mom    1  5  2  4  3
# 6    2   6    c   kid    1  3 NA NA  5
# 7    1   1    a   dad    2  3  2  4  3
# 8    1   2    b   mom    2  3  5  6  6
# 9    1   3    c   kid    2  2 NA NA  5
# 10   2   4    a   dad    2  2  6  2  6
# 11   2   5    b   mom    2  3  2  4  3
# 12   2   6    c   kid    2  2 NA NA  5
```

Comment: I find the non-purrr answer easier to understand and implement, but I need to start learning purrr!

Comment: @EricGreen Yes, I agree it takes some time to understand the syntax of the `purrr` package. So unless there are some performance issue, you `gather` approach would be a better approach.